# Is a tabIndex of -1 the same as having no tabIndex, or should you use undefined or null?

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility

I have a generic react component which is passed a prop value, based on this prop value I would sometimes like this component to have a tabIndex of 0 and other times I wouldn't.

If I assign it a value of 0 when it's needed, what could the alternative be when it's not needed? I'd basically like equivalent value as if the tabIndex prop wasn't present i.e. has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabindex="-1"` means it is still programatically focusable (with `.focus()` for example) but will not interfere with the tab order / focus order of the page. For clarity `tabindex="-1"` means the only way to focus the item is if you target it via JavaScript.

If you want you can just add and remove the attribute as you need it, but this would probably be unnecessary in most scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, so do you think it's ok to leave the default value as -1, I'm ok if it means the item can only be focused with javascript, as if it needs focus via other ways, the prop for that instance can set the tabIndex to 0.

Comment: I can't add or remove the attribute in the way it's currently structured as it always is present, unless I can define whether a property exists in an object based on a prop being present or not. Not sure that is possible.

Comment: Yup it should cause you no issues having `tabindex="-1"` on items, this is often how keyboard controls are added to drop-down menus etc. so it is a standard pattern and does not interfere with Assistive Tech, focus order etc.

Comment: Oh I thought there was a connection between keyboard controls and assistive tech, for instance if you added a tabIndex of 0 it would force that element to be focussed and potentially read by a screen reader if it was being skipped before.

Comment: Yes it does, sorry I meant `tabindex="-1"` will not interfere in any way. `tabindex="0"` will force an item in the focus order at the relevant point based on DOM order and a positive `tabindex` will make that item be focused according to it's `tabindex` number.

Comment: And the purpose of -1 is because some browsers, if you try to `.focus()` to an element and it does **not** have `tabindex="-1"`, then the browser will **not** move the focus to that element.  Having -1 allows the (keyboard) focus to move to the element when moved there programmatically.  In theory, you could have -1 on every piece of static text and it would not affect the keyboard user one bit.